# Copying directories in HDFS using the JAVA API

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How do I copy a directory in HDFS to another directory in HDFS?

I found the copyFromLocalFile functions that copy from the local FS to HDFS, but I want both of the source/destination to be in HDFS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [distcp](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/distcp.html) command.

The canonical use case for distcp is for transferring data between two HDFS clusters.
If  the  clusters  are  running  identical  versions  of  Hadoop,  the  hdfs  scheme  is
appropriate:

> % hadoop distcp hdfs://namenode1/foo hdfs://namenode2/bar

If you want to do it through Java code, see class [org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-tools/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/tools/DistCp.java) and call it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can try FileUtil.copy

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html

Comment: This will download all bytes from the hdfs to the local jvm and upload to the target hdfs; so it may not be efficient if you want to copy very large files.

Comment: Dont use it for the reasons @lyomi explained